# How do I find the contact info for the assignee on a patent?

Tags: us20130052896

I'm looking for Bruce Abraham's contact information for the decorative noodle patent ([US20130052896](http://www.google.com/patents/US20130052896)).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The information regarding this patent application is on the public record in the USPTO's Public PAIR database. The entire paper work history of a patent or published application filed since mid 2003 is visible to all. From the inventor's declaration:

[image]